# Filter data based on timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataset is below.

[image: Input]

What is the best way to create multiple new datasets with time stamp of 09:15:00, 10:15:00 so on..

Output dataset to be

[image: Output dataset]

Comment: please provide a reproducible example and the matching expected output

Comment: Unfortunately an image is not reproducible, we need minimal code which once run gives us your dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your datetime column is an index or a column without a name?
If its a column without a name:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"": "DateTime"})
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"]).dt.time

df_dict = {x: pd.DataFrame for x in df["Time"].unique()}
for key in df_dict.keys():
    df_dict[key] = df.query("Time.eq(@key)").reset_index(drop=True)

    print(f"{df_dict[key]}\n")
```